# Using the segue from master detail application with custom button.

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uistoryboardsegue, xcode-storyboard

So, I have a master detail application. So far an object is created at launch and added to the master list, the detail view works fine as well.

What I would like to do, is to let the user add object to the master list by pressing a button. I don´t need a new view for that though, I want to use the standard Detail View for this part.

When the user taps the "Add" button, a new object should be created and then go into the detailed view of that object. I thought, "hey, why not use the standard segue as well?"
So I added a **Bar Button Item** to the MasterView.

This my code from MasterViewController.m:

```
-(IBAction)addNewItem:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]){

        CoolItem *newItem;
        NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
        newItem = [[CoolItem alloc]initWithDate:today];

        [self.dataController addCoolItemWithItem:newItem];
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        detailViewController.coolItem = newItem;


    }
}
```

"showDetail" is the identifier of the standard segue that comes with the master detail template.

The result: Nothing! The method is not called at button tap.

I´ve made sure my button is connected to this method, (it does however shows up as a unwind segue in the document outline).

Any ideas on what goes wrong?

Comment: are you trying to use the add button to add another item to the tableview and go to the new item from table view to detail view?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what went wrong but I was able to achieve the desired functionality using the following code:

```
-(void)viewDidload {
      ...
      self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = 
     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd                                                                                                     
                            target:self
                            action:@selector(Add:)];    
}


-(IBAction)Add:(id)sender 
{
    // Create the new item and set it as active
    ...

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SegueName" sender:self];
}
```

Hope this helps
Yaron